# Mobile Safari: Differentiating between hitting the back button and swiping backwards through history

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

On iOS 8 Mobile Safari swiping from off screen left or close to off screen left you can move back through the browser's history as if you were hitting Safari's back button.

Both events fire the window popstate event. But I'd like to have a different interaction on the page based upon which event triggers the pop.

I've found this post about iOS 7 : [In iOS 7 Safari, how do you differentiate popstate events via edge swipe vs. the back/fwd buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662434/in-ios-7-safari-how-do-you-differentiate-popstate-events-via-edge-swipe-vs-the)

I'm going to assume nothing has changed but I want to see if anyone has come up with any other solutions or ideas.

Comment: If you figure out any good solution for this, I'd be interested to know about it too. :)

Comment: And me too :) !